# Do Node openfaas functions require a package.json in the deployment bundle?

Tags: node.js, npm, openfaas

Looking at `openfaas` [Node templates](https://github.com/openfaas/templates/tree/master/template/node14/function) there is a pattern of having a nested `package.json` in the `functions` folder.

Seeing a nested package.json file (*location other than the root*) in a non-monorepo npm package is code smell to me and causes some dev flow problems:

1. A nested `package-lock.json` artifact being committed
2. cloning the repo and running `npm ci` does not install all the dependencies

The latter is particularly painful. A developer cloning an openfaas repo for the first time and running `npm ci` or `npm i` will not have all the dependencies installed to run the function locally. Same issue for any continuous integration, like Jenkins, that runs automated tests.

So one could add the dependencies in the `function/package.json` to the root `package.json` (*prone to human error*). Or write scripts that `cd function && npm ci && cd .. && npm run start:whatever` to work around this but obviously that is a bit ridiculous.

- **Does `openfaas` require the package.json dependency manifest for publishing/runtime purposes?**
- **If not, why does `openfaas` suggest this nested `package.json` in `function` directory pattern for it's Node templates**